# Datatables serverside responsive does not work with extra column

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

When I comment the "responsive" in the script, everything would be OK but the table is not responsive. When I comment the last data column(for edit) in the script and enable responsive, the table is responsive but I don't have the last column. When I active both(last column and responsive) it does not fire the handler and stays in processing... What is wrong here?

```
      var table = $('.dataTable').DataTable({

            "bProcessing": true,
            "bServerSide": true,               
            "responsive": true,
            "sAjaxSource": "/View/test/test3Handler.ashx",

            "columns": [
                { 'data': 'field_1' },
                { 'data': 'field_2' },
                { 'data': 'field_3' },
                { 'data': 'field_4' },
                { 'data': 'field_5' },
                { 'data': 'field_6' },
                {
                    'data': null,
                    'sortable': false,
                    'searchable': false,
                    'render': function () {
                        return '<a class="editMe" role="button"><img src="/images/edit.png" width="25px" /></a>';
                    }
                },

            ],

        });


         <table id="dtbl" class="display dataTable">
           <thead>
              <tr style="text-align:left;">
                 <th>field_1</th>
                 <th>field_2</th>
                 <th>field_3</th>
                 <th>field_4</th>
                 <th>field_5</th>
                 <th>field_6</th>
                 <th>Edit</th>
              </tr>
           </thead>
                <tbody></tbody>
                <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                        <th><input type="search" placeholder="Search field_1"></th>
                        <th><input type="search" placeholder="Search field_2"> </th>
                        <th><input type="search" placeholder="Search field_3"></th>
                        <th><input type="search" placeholder="Search field_4"></th>
                        <th><input type="search" placeholder="Search field_5"></th>
                        <th><input type="search" placeholder="Search field_6"></th>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
            </table>
```

Comment: Well typos won't help `'sortabl': false,`

Comment: I have corrected it, but same problem

Comment: I found it. I had to add a column for edit also in the footer.